# WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/_next/webpack-hmr' failed: The operation couldn’t be completed. Socket is not connected

Tags: next.js

In my terminal I don't receive an error, but when I open my localhost I receive a blank page, after I touch the inspect but I don't know what I do, now in the console I receive two error
[Error] WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/_next/webpack-hmr' failed: The operation couldn’t be completed. Socket is not connected
and
[Error] WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/_next/webpack-hmr' failed: Could not connect to the server. (x4)
thanks

I expect to receive in localhost what I have before I was in the inspect